# MTIP MP92 Test 1 Scenario 1 - Card Indicates that it does not support Contactless

Tags: testing, smartcard, emv, mastercard

I'm running M-TIP MP92 Test 01 Scenario 01. The objective of the test is:

*"To ensure that the terminal terminates the transaction when the card indicates that it does not support Contactless - M/Chip".*

What I don't understand, is how a card indicates this. My terminal as it is right now is processing beyond the **Get Processing Options** step, which results in a failure from my testing tool. I've looked through the data being exchanged between the card and the tool up to that point, but I don't understand where this is.

```
    Select (2PAY.SYS.DDF01)
        Request : 00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
            Class    :00
            Ins      :A4
            P1       :04
            P2       :00
            Lc       :0E
            Data     :32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31
                Application: 2PAY.SYS.DDF01
            Le       :00
        Response: 6F 23 84 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 11 BF 0C 0E 61 0C 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60 87 01 01 90 00
            Data     : 6F 23 84 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 11 BF 0C 0E 61 0C 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60 87 01 01
                Tag 6F   : File Control Information (FCI) Template                        
                    Tag 84   : Dedicated File (DF) Name                                       : 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31
                        PPSE Directory File Name = 2PAY.SYS.DDF01
                    Tag A5   : File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template            
                        Tag BF 0C: File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Template   
                            Tag 61   : Application Template                                           
                                Tag 4F   : Application Identifier (AID)                                   : A0 00 00 00 04 30 60
                                Tag 87   : Application Priority Indicator                                 : 01
                                    Byte 1 bit 8  = 0      Application may be selected without confirmation of cardholder
                                           bit 7-5= 000    RFU
                                           bit 4-1= 0001   Order number in which the application is to be listed: 1
            SW1 SW2  : 90 00 (SW_OK)
    Select (Maestro)
        Request : 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60 00
            Class    :00
            Ins      :A4
            P1       :04
            P2       :00
            Lc       :07
            Data     :A0 00 00 00 04 30 60
                Application: Maestro
            Le       :00
        Response: 6F 2F 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60 A5 24 50 09 4D 50 39 32 20 76 32 20 32 BF 0C 16 5F 50 13 43 4F 4C 4C 49 53 5C 2A 2F 4D 50 39 32 5C 2A 2F 32 2E 32 90 00
            Data     : 6F 2F 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 30 60 A5 24 50 09 4D 50 39 32 20 76 32 20 32 BF 0C 16 5F 50 13 43 4F 4C 4C 49 53 5C 2A 2F 4D 50 39 32 5C 2A 2F 32 2E 32
                Tag 6F   : File Control Information (FCI) Template                        
                    Tag 84   : Dedicated File (DF) Name                                       : A0 00 00 00 04 30 60
                    Tag A5   : File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template            
                        Tag 50   : Application Label                                              : 4D 50 39 32 20 76 32 20 32
                            Text value = MP92 v2 2
                        Tag BF 0C: File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Template   
                            Tag 5F 50: Issuer URL                                                     : 43 4F 4C 4C 49 53 5C 2A 2F 4D 50 39 32 5C 2A 2F 32 2E 32
                                Text value = COLLIS\*/MP92\*/2.2
            SW1 SW2  : 90 00 (SW_OK)
    Get Processing Options
        Request : 80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00
            Class    :80
            Ins      :A8
            P1       :00
            P2       :00
            Lc       :02
            Data     :83 00
            Le       :00
        MCHIP Card Unique Key Derivation Results
            PAN:                             67 99 99 89 00 00 00 60 92 7F
            PAN Sequence Number:             01
            Cryptogram Version No.:          10
            ICC Master Key AC:               9E 15 20 43 13 F7 31 8A CB 79 B9 0B D9 86 AD 29
            Derived Card Unique Key:         9D A1 13 AD 92 46 DC 04 85 92 3B 86 94 08 DC DF
            ICC Master Key SMC:              CE 29 3B 8C C1 2A 97 73 79 EF 25 6D 76 10 94 92
            Derived Card Unique Key:         68 62 A7 40 F8 3E FE 97 E5 04 0D FB 10 85 46 CE
            ICC Master Key SMI:              46 64 94 2F E6 15 FB 02 E5 D5 7F 29 2A A2 B3 B6
            Derived Card Unique Key:         10 C4 F7 DF 68 75 B0 E5 EF 80 C7 AB 3B 80 9B F8
            ICC Master Key IDN:              94 C5 3B 6B 15 07 7F CB E5 40 7F 43 B5 AB FB 80
            Derived Card Unique Key:         AB 51 29 16 AE 08 1A 25 DF 76 D0 3E EC 9E 6B 40
        Response: 77 16 82 02 19 00 94 10 08 01 01 00 10 01 01 01 18 01 02 00 20 01 02 00 90 00
            Data     : 77 16 82 02 19 00 94 10 08 01 01 00 10 01 01 01 18 01 02 00 20 01 02 00
                Tag 77   : Response Message Template Format 2                             
                    Tag 82   : Application Interchange Profile [M/Chip, PayPass]              : 19 00
                        Byte 1 bit 8 = 0      RFU
                               bit 7 = 0      Offline static data authentication is NOT supported
                               bit 6 = 0      Offline dynamic data authentication is NOT supported
                               bit 5 = 1      Cardholder verification is supported
                               bit 4 = 1      Terminal risk management is to be performed
                               bit 3 = 0      Issuer authentication is supported using GENERATE AC command
                               bit 2 = 0      On device cardholder verification is NOT supported
                               bit 1 = 1      Combined DDA / GENERATE AC supported
                        Byte 2 bit 8 = 0      Only Mag Stripe profile supported [PayPass]
                               bit 7 = 0      RFU
                               bit 6 = 0      RFU
                               bit 5 = 0      RFU
                               bit 4 = 0      RFU
                               bit 3 = 0      RFU
                               bit 2 = 0      RFU
                               bit 1 = 0      RFU
                    Tag 94   : Application File Locator (AFL)                                 : 08 01 01 00 10 01 01 01 18 01 02 00 20 01 02 00
                        AFL (1) = 08 01 01 00
                            SFI (decimal)                   = 1
                            Start record                    = 1
                            End record                      = 1
                            Number of records needed
                            for offline data authentication = 0
                        AFL (2) = 10 01 01 01
                            SFI (decimal)                   = 2
                            Start record                    = 1
                            End record                      = 1
                            Number of records needed
                            for offline data authentication = 1
                        AFL (3) = 18 01 02 00
                            SFI (decimal)                   = 3
                            Start record                    = 1
                            End record                      = 2
                            Number of records needed
                            for offline data authentication = 0
                        AFL (4) = 20 01 02 00
                            SFI (decimal)                   = 4
                            Start record                    = 1
                            End record                      = 2
                            Number of records needed
                            for offline data authentication = 0
            SW1 SW2  : 90 00 (SW_OK)
```

Comment: APDU traces? Specifically what SELECT commands did you send so far and what did you get in response?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Added the trace to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Card Profile MP 92 due to AIP tag 0x82 Byte 2 Bit 8 - EMV Contactless NOT supported (i.e. Only Mag Stripe profile supported [PayPass] in your traces).

According to MasterCard rules, M/Chip Contactless-Magstripe should not be supported for Maestro cards in Europe.

This restriction should be indicated for Maestro Contactless RID/AID profile in Tag 0x9F1D Byte 3 Bit 8. Tag 0x9F1D Byte 3 should be 0x80 i.e Contactless-Mastripe not supported.

When you fix your Maestro terminal profile the Terminal Kernel should reject this Contactless card and ask to use Chip as expected by this test scenario.

Comment: So is my understanding correct that: The card only supports contactless magstripe, the terminal indicates through 9F1D that it only supports contactless EMV, and since there is no common support for either, the transaction should fail?

Comment: Yes, terminal should ask in this case to use EMV Contact chip. This is specific Maestro requirement. The requirements could be different for different markets or acquirer specific implementations. In theory can be created Maestro Contactless-Magswipe profile like with this card example. In practice, less and less card schemes continue support Contactless-Magswipe forcing to use Contactless-EMV profiles.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. I've been able to confirm that the terminal is properly loading and even returning to me XXXX8XX.. in tag 9F1D. I'm not sure why the transaction is continuing past GET PO. I'll see if the hardware vendor can be of any help.

Comment: Hey @raydowe , I came across your question a couple of years later and I'm facing the same issue. Did you find an answer from your vendor?